# SpringBoot app container can not execute pdbedit command

Tags: docker, spring-boot, containers, samba

Recently, I have deployed two container into Docker is SpringBoot webapp and MySQL via docker-compose.yml. In my webapp source code, LogIn page have to check SAMBA user of CentOS, if user/password is correct the next page will be displayed.

Webapp run in local pdbedit command check very smoothy, everything is OK. But when containerize, my webapp can not execute pdbedit command so display error: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdbedit": error=2, No such file or directory`

In addition, two container start and run normally I still access LogIn page (but cannot login).

So, can you help me what should I do? And how to implement a query from container to OS's services or another container.

Here is my controller:
(...cut off)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/access", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String access(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("user")User user,
        Model model) throws IOException{
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user.getUsername());
            request.getSession().setAttribute("pass", user.getPassword());
            NTLMPassword ntlm = new NTLMPassword();
            String password2 = ntlm.encode(user.getPassword());
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pdbedit","-u",user.getUsername(),"-w");
        Process p = pb.start();
```

....(cut off)

Thanks and best regards.
[image]

Comment: In your Spring Boot docker image you'll have to install pdbedit 

Whether or not it will then access the parent OS's Samba database I'm not sure. If not you'll have to work out a way of remotely verifying the user and password.

Comment: @PaulNUK thanks for your reply. My requirement is SpringBoot, SAMBA and MYSQL all in containerize. I have tried to use SAMBA container but I cant, so I installed SAMBA service in CentOS for test. About `In your Spring Boot docker image you'll have to install pdbedit` I dont understand what your mean. Can you teach me more details about that? Thanks.

Comment: Well your error is that the Spring Boot Docker image doesn't have pdbedit installed. So in your docker file for Spring Boot, you'll have to do an apt-get update followed by an apt-get install of whatever package contains pdbedit.

But seeing as you will be remotely checking the password from Spring Boot against a separate container running Samba, I'm not sure this will work anyway. You might have to look at another way of authenticating the user/password.